# htaccess redirect in joomla WITHOUT landing on index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I've added an redirect from an old domain to my new domain in the .htaccess file of my Joomla 3.x site, running on Apache.

This is the code I'm trying to get working;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.co\.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This succeeds in redirecting any incorrect domain to my new domain, but does NOT put me on the corresponding sub-page.

So, for example, I type in the following address ..;

```
http:\\old.com\calendar
```

... and I WANT to end up at;

```
http:\\newdomain.co.uk\calendar
```

But instead, I get directed to;

```
http:\\newdomain.co.uk\index.php
```

Can anyone help me get the redirect working to land me on the corresponding sub-page?

For the record, the Joomla site's SEO settings are as follows (and work as you would expect - site pages do not generally include `index.php` in the URL and correspond to the menu item alias);

```
Search Engine Friendly URLs - YES
Use URL rewriting           - YES
Adds Suffix to URL          - NO
Unicode Aliases             - NO
```

The COMPLETE .htaccess file looks like this - I don't know if Joomla's .htaccess definitions are affecting the redirect that I've put in place;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

suPHP_ConfigPath /whatever/php.ini

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.co\.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=10"
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide some insight!

Comment: You are rewriting a lot of stuff to `index.php` before already – so when your new Rules you added below that are evaluated, the (internal) request URI most likely _is_ `index.php` already. So move those new rules further up.

Comment: Wow - simple as that.  I think I had my head in some programming language where the order was irrelevant.  That worked perfectly - thank you so much.

If you add your response as a separate answer, I'll be happy to mark it as 'correct' and add to your rep (or however this thing works!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rewriting a lot of stuff to `index.php` before already – so when your new Rules you added below that are evaluated, the (internal) request URI most likely *is* `index.php` already.

So move those new rules further up.

Comment: Thanks again, CBroe.  ^_^

I couldn't vote up your answer because my rep is insufficient at the moment, but I'll probably use this site a little more in the future (so hopefully I can do so later).  Thanks again and best wishes.